# How to execute GO statement in Entity Framework Migrations CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

when we try to create a new database from our product is gives and error in mirgrations. We are using GO statement in the migrations which is causing the error. Following is the error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'GO'

Following is the migration class created :

```
namespace One234C.SRC.DomainModel.ORMapping.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class AdditionOfBatchCostedFlagColumn : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("Service.ServiceOrderComponentDetails", "BatchCostedFlag", c => c.Byte(nullable: true));
            Sql("GO");
            string queryStr ="UPDATE [Service].ServiceOrderComponentDetails " +
                              "SET BatchCostedFlag = 1";
            Sql(queryStr);
            AlterColumn("Service.ServiceOrderComponentDetails", "BatchCostedFlag", c => c.Byte(nullable: false, defaultValue:0));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("Service.ServiceOrderComponentDetails", "BatchCostedFlag");
        }

    }
}
```

Is there anyway to do this operation without using go statement in EntityFramework.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx :

GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.